# Which length is inserted between the lines?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I want to put five images with a height of `.2\textheight` onto a single page. However, there is a tiny gap between two images which, I think, leads to the last image beeing put on a second page.

I do not know which length has to be set to `0pt` to avoid this.

**Update:** Setting `\lineskip` to `0pt` removes the gap, but still only four images are put on the first page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\myheight
\setlength\myheight{5cm}
\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth{16cm}
\usepackage[
  textheight=5\myheight,
  textwidth=\mywidth,
  a4paper,
  centering
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\begin{document}\raggedright
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is `\offinterlineskip`, but you should use it only in a group, but I think it will not be sufficient

Comment: Re-defining `\offinterlineskip` to `{}` does not help.

Comment: I did not say you should redefine `\offinterlineskip`, did I? ;-) Just say `\offinterlineskip` in such cases, but as I wrote also, it might be not sufficient

Comment: No, you didn't ;-) I was just thinking that it inserts some lengths and/or glues, which is obviously nonsense. 

I've looked it up in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `\lineskip` which needs to be set to `0pt`. However, it is advisable to limit this change to the included images by putting it into a group `{...}`. (The vbox argument is already put in a group.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\myheight
\setlength\myheight{5cm}
\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth{16cm}
\usepackage[
  textheight=5\myheight,
  textwidth=\mywidth,
  a4paper,
  centering
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}\raggedright%
  \vbox to \textheight{\setlength\lineskip{0pt}% or: \offinterlineskip
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have found `\lineskip` in the suggested related questions, too. But if I compile your example, the last image is still put on a second page.

Comment: You can put the whole thing into a vbox of definite height (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

```
[...]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}\offinterlineskip\enlargethispage{1pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=\mywidth, height=\myheight]{example-image-a}%
\end{document}
```